# Dropwizard MetricRegistry with Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, micrometer, spring-boot-2

I was upgrading spring boot to 2 in one of the project.
I am facing issue with `@Autowire metricRegistry:MetricRegistry`

I had read upgrade guide where it is mentioned that Metrics are replaced by Micrometer's MeterRegistry.

Since, Dropwizard MetricRegistry is havely used in current project, it is difficult to replace it.

Is there any possibility to use Dropwizard MetricRegistry with spring boot 2 and `@Autowire metricRegistry:MetricRegistry` get work?

Comment: It isn't replaced with its own, it is replaced with the Micrometer version of the MeterRegistry. Moving to that shouldn't be to big of a change.

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum,
Can you let me know how can it be replace in following? 


`extractDataSource(@Autowire metricRegistry:MetricRegistry) { `
`DataSource ds = ABC_Class.build(metricRegistry);`
`}`


While ABC_Class has build method as follows

`HikariDataSource build(metricRegistry:Option[MetricRegistry]) {`
`HikariDataSource ds....`
`metricRegistry.foreeach(ds.setMetricRegistry)`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Fyi: Spring Boot 2 reached its end of OSS support life a while ago, you should upgrade to the latest 3.x: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

You should take a look at [`DropwizardMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/b81c63bf9b87f6e1dd149d503133e7f1a008b2e8/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/dropwizard/DropwizardMeterRegistry.java), you can use it as:

```java
@Bean
DropwizardMeterRegistry dropwizardMeterRegistry(...) {
    return new DropwizardMeterRegistry();
}
```

Then you can inject `MeterRegistry` (Micrometer's API) in new code and keep using `MetricsRegistry` (Dropwizard's API) in old code.

Comment: Hi Jonatan, Thanks for reply! will try this and revert.